# What Cultural Factors Dictate the Parameters of a "Life Debt" Tradition?

Tags: culture, earth-like, earth, medieval

A common trope in fiction is the "life debt," wherein two characters become "bound together by a bond of oath" because one has saved the other's life.

- Often the two characters are strangers when the lifesaving incident occurs
- Often one of the characters comes from a primitive culture wherein the tradition of a "life debt" is an unavoidable consequence
- either the person who gets saved feels indebted to the savior, and thereafter swears allegiance
- or the person who is the savior prevents the saved person from "meeting his fate" and thereafter must take responsibility for changing fate by watching over the person who was saved
- the story then may include a role-reversal scenario that absolves the subservient person from further responsibility

We consumers of media have seen this concept of a "life debt" haphazardly bandied about... from Gilligan's Island to Star Wars.

What is the determining cultural factor that governs which person becomes indebted, subservient or responsible?

(Wikipedia defines the "life debt" as a purely "literary phenomenon" - but can you think of any real-world cultures that are **known** to have this tradition?)

Comment: Isn't that history question?

Comment: Suggest this on the sci-fi&fantasy SE.

Comment: None, I don't think, with the possible exception of the Japanese, and that's a mere guess. ***Humans are selfish.***  Giving themselves away in servitude simply doesn't jive very well with anyone who was free to begin with. Even if society somehow embraced this rule there would always be individuals who would reject it, maybe even going to extreme lengths (killing their saviors) to avoid becoming indebted to that degree. Furthermore, there are not too many circumstances under which people save each other's lives, so there wouldn't be much of an opportunity for this tradition to develop.

Comment: @AndreiROM I would be not so sure about that. Not clear which kinda obligation OP talks about, I mean how obligate are those obligation. Saving live could be strong relation bond, but depends on situation, and not necessary in a way : *I own your live now*.

Comment: @AndreiROM: If you believe in the supernatural, selfishness may lead to very different decisions. For example, from a selfish point of view, a suicide attack is the most stupid thing you can imagine. Unless you believe in an afterlife where you get rewarded for it. So if you believe that ignoring that "life debt" will fare badly for you (be it in afterlife, or be it in your future fate on earth), the selfish thing is to not ignore it.

Comment: @MolbOrg: It's not a history question if the entire trope is false. The only information that I found on this is Wikipedia, which gives the definition: "A life debt is a *literary phenomenon* in which someone whose life is saved or spared by another becomes indebted..."

Comment: This sounds like a question that fits into world building, as long as the real world sentence at the end is removed. This is a scenario that may not make much sense in our world, but could be easily fit into a literary or fantastical world.  The easiest explanations being: a highly face based society, a very organized empire with the institutionalization of slavery, or most likely a world in which Karma or Religion play a huge role. Afterlife or just Active Gods.

Comment: @EverettSteed I believe it is history/Cultural Studies question and Yes/No answer depend on what you mean under obligations and I believe there is Yes answer in certain cases, based on what have a place in modern life. It depends on the situation, on people and culture in terms of - How far the gratitude stretches. Was there a law with had enforced such behavior - I doubt but do not exclude that, blood brothers is a part of such mindset. An orphan, which would die from hunger on the streets otherwise, might have son/daughter gratitude to his/its adoptive parents etc.

Comment: There have certainly been societies where bankruptcy meant that the bankrupt himself was sold as a slave. Were there societies where this treatment extended to his wife and children?  I don't know, but I can imagine a society where the debt might be expressed in person-years such that descendants of debt-slaves might discharge their inherited share of the debt and become free again. Not a *nice* society but not necessarily a primitive one.